# Facebook streaming graph live comments works partly

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-live-api

I'm testing Facebook [Live Comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/server-sent-events/endpoints/live-comments) (<--Link) API. On some live feeds it works partly, which means part of the comments shows in the original video but not in the HTTP GET reply. It filtered specific people, including myself.

On another streaming it was just polling, without showing any comment.

I need to get the comments while they are being posted, WITH the user id who sent it (that's why the Graph comments polling system is not suitable. No from_id)

How do I make the Live Comments work without this unclear filtering?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, due to recent Graph API changes, you won't be able to get the `from` field in many cases.

If this live video is on a Page, you can access the `from` field if you're using a page access token.  If the live video is pretty much anywhere else, you're not going to be able to get the `from` field.

Also note that there are new throttling limits.  Since you're getting comments on a video object, you can use the SSE endpoints to avoid these limits:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/server-sent-events  Note that an SSE endpoint for comments is not available on other object types.

Comment: But why does the live comments http request returns only some of the users comments? Some users are being filtered, yet there is no filter parameter in the link above.

Comment: @mik Some users may have their preferences set in such a way that allows you to access this data.  In other cases, the comments might even be from a page and not a user.

Comment: It doesn't make sense, as I've created a new user without any preference change, and his comments still didn't show up. And all the comments are from users, it's just that specific ones are being blocked.

Comment: P.S. It doesn't make a difference if I own the video or not.

Comment: @mik Without a specific example, I don't know what else to tell you.  That `from` field isn't always available.